# show message on click on the top of window without scrolling up to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

on an open cart project , i just want when click on addToCart button show me message item added in the top of screen wherever the item is , not to scroll up and then show message, help will be appreciated.

Comment: will you payme to create this?Anyways using Javascript and css you can create something like that. like when you click on add to cart button ..It will flying and added into cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I have basic cart and I used *jquery-modal*.

1. Include *jquery.modal.min.js* to html.
2. Call *modal()* function:

   $(".alert-box.alert").modal();

*".alert-box.alert"* - div container with message.

When I add item to cart I have message in center of the screen.

You can find more examples here: [jQuery Modal](http://jquerymodal.com/).

Hope my answer help you to find your solution.